# PHP, MySQL Per row output

Tags: php, mysql

Been all over the place and spent 8 hours working loops and math...still cant get it...

I am writing a CP for a customer.  The input form will allow them to add a package deal to their web page.  Each package deal is stored in mysql in the following format

id    header    item1    item2    item3...item12    price    savings

The output is a table with 'header' being the name of the package and each item being 1 of the items in the package stored in a row within the table, then the price and amount saved (all of this is input via a form and INSERT statement by the customer, that part works) stored rows as well.

Here is my PHP:

```
include 'dbconnect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM md ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

      //Print 4 tables with header, items, price, savings
      //Go to next row (on main page) and print 4 more items
      //Do this until all tables have been printed
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($conn);
```

Right now the main page is simpley a header div, main div, content wrap and footer div.

Ideal HTML output of a 'package' table, not perfect and a little confusing

$header
    $item1
    $item2
    ect...
    $price$savings

I basically want the PHP to print this 4 times per row on the main page and then move to the next row and print 4 times and continue until there are no more items in the array.  So it could be row 1 4 tables, row 2 4 tables, row 3 3 tables.

Long, confusing and frustrating.  I about to just do 1 item per row..please help

Jake

Answer (score 0):

You say "tables", but do you mean cells?

The basic flow would be:

```
$res = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_numrows($res) == 0) {
     ... say there's nothing to show ...
} else {
    ... print table header ...
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        ... print row ...
    }
    ... print table footer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i get your question right you need to use a loop, something like a `for`

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
       //print table (change $i values to change number of loops)
   }
}
```

if i didnt get it right, please post an example of how the table should look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items_per_line=4;
$counter=$items_per_line;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if($counter <1){
    $counter=$items_per_line;
    // goto next pages
  }
  // print   header etc.
  $counter--;
}
```